# Problema ao criar log

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

To criando um log para meu sistema pra saber que fez alteração na informações, só que o jeito que montei está dando Fatal error: Call to undefined function anti_injection() in:

alguém pode ajudar ou me dar algum exemplo de log de alteração de registro em php/mysql?

minha tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `LOGS` (
`LOGID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`HORA` datetime NOT NULL,
`IP` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`MENSAGEM` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`LOGID`),
KEY `HORA` (`HORA` )
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

o arquivo para gerar log:

```
<?php


include 'adm/config.php';


//ABAIXO CRIAMOS A FUNÇÃO QUE IRÁ AUTOMATIZAR A CRIAÇÃO DOS LOGS NO BANCO
function logs($x){     // RECEBE POR PARAMETRO A VARIÁVEL $x QUE SERÁ A MENSAGEM A SER GRAVADA NO BANCO DE DADOS.

    $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // SALVA O IP DO VISITANTE
    $HORA = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // SALVA A DATA E HORA ATUAL (formato MySQL)

    // MONTANDO A QUERY PARA INSERIR NO BANCO DE DADOS
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `LOGS` (HORA,IP,MENSAGEM) VALUES ('$HORA', '$IP', '$x')";  //ONDE "$x" É A VARIÁVEL QUE ARMAZENA A MENSAGEM QUE VOCÊ QUER INSERIR NO BANCO


    if (mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error())){ // EXECUTA A QUERY OU MOSTRA O ERRO, CASO OCORRA.
             return true;   //VERIFICA  SE DEU CERTO, SE SIM RETORNA TRUE
    }

    else{
             return false; // VERIFICA  SE DEU ERRADO, SE SIM,  RETORNA FALSE

    }


}


logs($x); // AQUI CHAMAMOS A FUNÇÃO QUE CRIAMOS PARA EXECUTAR A INSERÇÃO NO BANCO DE DADOS


    //SE REMOVER O COMENTÁRIO DO CÓDIGO  ABAIXO, PODERÁ IMPRIMIR A MENSAGEM DIRETAMENTE NO NAVEGADOR E CONFERIR SE O PROCESSO FOI REALIZADO COM SUCESSO OU NÃO
 /*  << INÍCIO DO COMENTÁRIO


if(logs($x)){   // VERIFICA O RETORNO DA FUNÇÃO, SE DEU CERTO OU ERRADO

    echo "Logs inseridos no banco";  //  EM CASO DE TER REALIZADO FUNÇÃO CORRETAMENTE, MOSTRA NO NAVEGADOR "Logs inseridos no banco"


}

else{

    echo "Logs não inseridos no banco"; //  EM CASO DE NÃO TER REALIZADO FUNÇÃO CORRETAMENTE, MOSTRA NO NAVEGADOR "Logs não inseridos no banco""
}
 */ //FIM DO COMENTÁRIO

mysql_close(); // FECHA A CONEXÃO COM O MySQL

?>
```

e nas paginas que quero q gere o logo coloco assim:

```
$x = 'Logs gravados';
include 'crialog.php';
```

Meu arquivo config que está acusando o erro nas linhas 13 e 19

```
<?php

$lc_titulo="World Trotter Com Imp e Exp Ltda";

$dbhost="localhost"; /* servidor */
$dbuser="root"; /* usuário do banco de dados */
$dbpasswd="rc010368"; /* senha do banco de dados */
$dbname="estoqueprod"; /* nome do banco de dados */
$conexao = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd,$dbname) or die ("não foi possível a conexão, verifique os dados $dbname.");
//mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("não foi possível o acesso ao banco de dados $dbname.");

// ANTI-INJECTION
function anti_injection($sql){
   $sql = preg_replace("/( from |select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/", "" ,$sql);
   $sql = trim($sql);
   $sql = strip_tags($sql);
   $sql = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $sql : addslashes($sql);
   return $sql;
}
?>
```

as linhas 13 a 19 são:

```
function anti_injection($sql){
   $sql = preg_replace("/( from |select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/", "" ,$sql);
   $sql = trim($sql);
   $sql = strip_tags($sql);
   $sql = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $sql : addslashes($sql);
   return $sql;
}
```

Comment: A função `anti_injection` não existe ou o código está tentando invoca-la antes dela ser incluída.

Comment: no meu arquivo config.php tem a função function anti_injection($sql){
   $sql = preg_replace("/( from |select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/", "" ,$sql);
   $sql = trim($sql);
   $sql = strip_tags($sql);
   $sql = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $sql : addslashes($sql);
   return $sql;

Comment: Poste o código do arquivo que gera o erro.

Comment: function anti_injection($sql){
   $sql = preg_replace("/( from |select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/", "" ,$sql);
   $sql = trim($sql);
   $sql = strip_tags($sql);
   $sql = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $sql : addslashes($sql);
   return $sql;

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare anti_injection() (previously declared in C:\AppServ\www\estoquewtprod\adm\config.php:20) in C:\AppServ\www\estoquewtprod\adm\config.php on line 26

Comment: Esse último erro você está tentando criar uma função que já existe. O ideal é você postar o código do `config.php` na sua pergunta. (Clique em [edit]) e onde em qual linha está dando erro (na sua pergunta também).

Comment: coloquei lá na pergunta